# How to find the repeating shapes in an image?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

For example I have this image and I want to find the repeating shapes. The repeating shapes are firstly the top 3 vertical lines, secondly the left and right sides of the object here have the same shape repeating over and over:

[image]

I thought perhaps just taking slices of one dimension from the image horizontally and vertically and then trying to test for repeating patterns in the one dimension. Is there a computer graphics way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can extract shape. Then use shape descriptors like moments to compare your shape

Comment: what about extracting connectedComponents and then using template matching.